# AngularJS - Multiple calls to the same service in a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Is it a bad code design if I put multiple calls to the same service in a single function? Each call to the service returns a value. Are there other better ways of implementing this?

For example:

```
$scope.getAdditionalInfo = () => {
        ExampleService
            .methodName($scope.parameter)
            .then(function (res) {
               //do things here
            }, function (err) {
                alert(err.message);
                console.log(err);
            });
        ExampleService
            .methodName2($scope.parameter)
            .then(function (res) {
               //do things here
            }, function (err) {
                alert(err.message);
                console.log(err);
            });
        ExampleService
            .methodName3($scope.parameter)
            .then(function (res) {
               //do things here
            }, function (err) {
                alert(err.message);
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
```

Comment: you might want to expose all those combined calls as one method in your service, and encapsulate all that concatenated calls - and returns to outside one single promise with the last value

Comment: No, there is absolutely nothing wrong with this if those method calls are what the method is supposed to do. The only drawback might be the size of the function body, when it gets too long (depends on the "do things here") you might want to split it up into three smaller parts and call them.